# How to create mySQL database from android application

Tags: java, android, mysql

i have an android application that connects to a server to send data to mysql database, i need a way to create that same database but in another server. Is there a way that i can create the database in the server from my android application? so i dont need to interact directly with the server mysel. I part from the suppose that the other server already has mysql installed

Comment: Like...to copy the database from one server to another?  Within an Android app?

Comment: no, just create the clean database in a given server from the android app